# Are multiple foreign keys allowed?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables and I want multiple foreign keys.

```
Users Table
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idUsers  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Username | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Password | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Friends Table
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idUser   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idFriend | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Status   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Groups Table
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idGroup   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| GroupName | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Members Table
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idGroup  | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idMember | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the foreign key for my Members Table so that the idGroup and idMember both correspond to the Users table idUsers.

```
ALTER TABLE `GroupOrder`.`Friends` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `idFriend`
FOREIGN KEY (`idFriend`)
REFERENCES `GroupOrder`.`Users` (`idUsers`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I want to make another foreign key in the Friends table that corresponds to the Users table. Am I'm doing in wrong. Everytime I do this I get an error.

```
ALTER TABLE `GroupOrder`.`Friends` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `idFriend`
FOREIGN KEY (`idUser` , `idFriend`)
REFERENCES `GroupOrder`.`Users` (`idUsers` , `idUsers`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Error

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'GroupOrder.#sql-2fce_1e' (errno: 150)
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `GroupOrder`.`Friends` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `idFriend`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idUser` , `idFriend`)
  REFERENCES `GroupOrder`.`Users` (`idUsers` , `idUsers`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'Friends' already exists
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `Friends` (
  `idUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idFriend` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idUser_idx` (`idFriend`),
  KEY `idUser_idx1` (`idUser`,`idFriend`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: you didnt show `GroupOrder` Table

Comment: GroupOrder is the database

Comment: You seem to be trying to define 2 foreign keys with the same name. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming friends is a many to many mapping from users to users.  This sort of implies friendship can be one-way, but that isn't necessarily wrong.

You already mapped idfriend in friends to idusers in users, now map iduser in friends to idusers in users.

```
ALTER TABLE `GroupOrder`.`Friends` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `idFriend2`
FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`)
REFERENCES `GroupOrder`.`Users` (`idUsers`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Now, you probably want to enforce uniqueness of iduser and idfriend in friends so you don't have repetition.

```
alter table `grouporder`.friends`
add unique(oduser, idfriend);
```